# Did Bibi Maryam really fast or merely pretended?

Tags: tafseer, prophet-isa, maryam

I don't understand the last part of verse 26 of chapter 19. Whether Bibi Maryam was told to fast or to pretend to fast?

If we take first meaning, then how can she drink and eat while fasting as mentioned in the same verse.

If we take second meaning, then how Allah (or her son Isa (A.S)) can command her to lie.

Thanks.

Comment: Zakaria fasted in a similar manner.

Comment: The fasting of the earlier ummahs was not identical to the fasting as prescribed to Muhammed in Islam. Some ummahs had to fast straight 24 hours without a drop of water or a morsel of food while for others merely abstaining from alcohol or cooked food would suffice. You can look up a course on  comparative religion for more details.

Answer (score 3):

> فَكُلِي وَاشْرَبِي وَقَرِّي عَيْنًا فَإِمَّا تَرَيِنَّ مِنَ الْبَشَرِ
> أَحَدًا **فَقُولِي** إِنِّي نَذَرْتُ لِلرَّحْمَـنِ صَوْمًا **فَلَنْ
> أُكَلِّمَ الْيَوْمَ إِنْسِيًّا**
>
> Eat and drink and rejoice. And if you see any human being **say**, 'I have vowed a fast to the Gracious God. **Therefore, I will not speak with any human being today**.' ([19:26](http://tanzil.net/#19:26))

The core meaning of the word **صَوْم** is to abstain. It is also used for abstinence from speaking and walking.

In the verse, it is evident from **فَلَنْ أُكَلِّمَ الْيَوْمَ إِنْسِيًّا** (Therefore, I will not speak with any human being today) that she was observing a 'fast of silence'.

One may ask further: how can God ask her to *tell* others that she is fasting when she was observing a 'fast of silence'? This is also clarified in the verse 19:29.

> **فَأَشَارَتْ إِلَيْهِ** قَالُوا كَيْفَ نُكَلِّمُ مَنْ كَانَ فِي الْمَهْدِ صَبِيًّا
>
> **She pointed to the child**. They said, "How shall we talk to someone who is a child in the cradle?" ([19:29](http://tanzil.net/#19:29))

**فَأَشَارَتْ إِلَيْهِ** clarifies that she was supposed to tell them by gestures not by words.

Answer (score -2):

From what I know, siti maryam is fast of silence. Siti Maryam shows the prophet Isa and clarifies not by her words but directly from the prophet Isa who has given miracles from Allah SWT. You can continue to read after 26 : 19.